# Alternative to CGPathAddEllipseInRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm wondering, is there an alternative to `CGPathAddElipseInRect` for drawing an ellipse? It works well and all, but I need a custom ellipse that has less steeper curves. Any thing else that can be done? I am using this path with `CTFramesetterCreateFrame` in `CoreText` so I can draw text within different shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No...

### ...But it can be done with Core Graphics

You would have to use something like `CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint`, `CGPathAddCurveToPoint` or `CGPathAddArcToPoint` to create a custom path for you ellipse. If your not familiar with how control points for bezier paths work you can starts by reading [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). You don't need to read the math part about it, just look at this image (from Wikipedia).

[image: A bezier curve with control points (from Wikipedia)]

**For the `...AddCurveTo...` method:**

Your current point is **p<sub>0</sub>** and the end point is **p<sub>3</sub>**. The two control points are **p<sub>1</sub>** and **p<sub>2</sub>**.

**For the `...AddQuadCurveTo..` method:**

Same as above but with only one control point.

**For the `...AddArcTo..` method:**

Doen't use control points. Instead uses a fixed radius.

---

### ...You can also create the path with UIBezierPath if you prefer

There is also similar methods on UIBezier path like `addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:` or `addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:`. The bezier path can then be converted to a CGPath but that shouldn't be necessary if your familiar with Core Graphics.

Comment: An even better introduction to control points would be any vector graphics program, such as VectorDesigner, Opacity, or Illustrator. The points that you place with the Pen tool are anchor points (in PostScript/Quartz/{NS,UI}BezierPath, these are the destinations of `moveto`, `lineto`, and `curveto` operations), and the points that you drag out when placing anchor points and that are connected to anchor points via thin straight lines are control points. Paths in graphics programs are usually cubic (`AddCurveTo`), not quadratic (`AddQuadCurveTo`).

Comment: @CoDEFRo: I'm saying you can use Illustrator to see the difference between anchor points and control points. You certainly could transcribe coordinates back and forth, but there are far easier ways to do that, and there is no substitute for actually writing the code, at least once, just to understand what's going on. Even reading it is not a substitute—the very act of writing it aids understanding.

Comment: @Peter Hosey - Ah alright. I ask because in the future I'm going to have to make more complex shapes, like a circle that has curves to make it look like a cloud shape. I wasn't really sure if it could be accomplished with vector graphics, but I guess now it could? I do plan on implementing the code and playing with it, but when you say "there are easier ways to transcribe points" what would those be (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: @David Rönnqvist - Thank you for that long well written out answer. I think you made a typo in the first part where you said the current point was p1 but I believe really it is p0? I tried making the edit but it didnt let me.

Comment: @CoDEFRo: [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity) and [PaintCode](http://paintcodeapp.com/). The former is more powerful and designed for creating static resolution-independent images, whereas the latter is streamlined for the singular purpose of generating code (though there are a few rudimentary export options). Opacity is also cheaper, but not on the MAS, whereas PaintCode is $10 more and MAS-exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `UIBezierPath` and then get its `CGPath` property.

How you create this path will depend on your needs. The method `+(UIBezierPath *) bezierPathWithOvalInRect:` looks like it most closely resembles `CGPathAddElipseInRect`.

You can also use its fill and stroke methods to draw into the current context.